# Most performant way to clear RWTexture2D

Tags: c++, gpu, directx-11

I was wondering what would be the quickest / most performant way to clear a 2D texture using DirectX 11?

Context: I am using an RWTexture object as a head pointer to implement linked lists on the GPU (essentially, to implement Order-Independent Transparency as known from the [AMD Tech Demo](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/06/2041_final.pdf)) and I need to reset this buffer to a fixed value every Frame.

The following ideas come to my mind:

- Declare it as a Render Target and use ClearRenderTargetView to set it. Seems unnatural to me since I don't actually render to it directly, also I am not sure if it actually works with an uint datatype
- Actually Map it as a render target and render a fullscreen quad, using the pixel shader to set the value
- Use a compute shader to set the fixed value

Is there some obvious way I am missing or an API for this that I am not aware of?

Comment: `ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint` and `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat` is better and simpler if you need to clear, the best solution would be to not have to clear.

Comment: Oh well that was exactly what I was looking for. Should have found that by myself, thats a little embarassing. Anyway, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by user galop1n, [ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff476391(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff476390(v=vs.85).aspx) are the way to go here.